# Qemu & VNC - how to use absolute pointing device

Tags: vnc, qemu

I'm using QEMU with VNC for display running a Windows XP guest OS. When I connect with a VNC client, the mouse pointer position is pretty badly correlated to where my real mouse pointer is.

Is there an absolute pointing device option that can be used with the VNC display interface??

Comment: What VNC client are you using? I'm having the same problem...

Comment: I'm using CORD on Mac.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Adding the '-usbdevice tablet' option to my qemu command fixed the problem for me.

Answer (score 1):

The above accepted answer worked for me adding the tablet USB type.  If you using Libvirt here is XML config:

```
<input type='tablet' bus='usb'/>
```

(I can't comment, so a new answer is what I have to do.)

Comment: It requires an explanation please